# "MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket" for Primary node in MongoDB replica set

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have Spring microservices running on Azure Kubernetes cluster and connected to MongoDB replica-set(3 nodes).
After running properly for some time, we get the following error:

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches 
ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. 
Client view of cluster state is 
{type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[
{address=mongo01.myhost.cloud:27017, type=UNKNOWN, 
state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, 
caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}, 
{address=mongo02.myhost.cloud:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, 
roundTripTime=2.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}, 
{address=mongo03.myhost.cloud:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, 
roundTripTime=1.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}];
```

As seen in the error log, the primary node is not able to connect whereas the two secondary nodes are connected.

- I am not able to understand why this error occurs after successfully running the application for some time?
- What can be the possible fix for the same?

If I connect to the same MongoDB replica-set through application running on my local system, I don't face this issue.

I referred to some other resources, like [Springboot fails even if one replica member goes down](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/springboot-fails-even-if-one-replica-member-goes-down/13668) and [JIRA-MongoDB: MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3274), but in no vein.

Versions:
`MongoDB: 4.4.1`
`Java: 11`
`Spring boot: 2.2.4-RELEASE`

I would be grateful for any help here.

Comment: How did you setup Kuberenetes cluster? Bare-metal or some cloud solution? How did you deployed MongoDB apps to Kubernetes - could you share instruction that you used? Could you share some logs from the broken pod by using command `kubectl logs {broken-pod}` (As I understand, this is what you mean by node?). Please add missing info to your post.

Comment: @Mikolaj It is an Azure Cloud solution. The error message that I have shared is from the logs of the broken pod. I have tried to keep it crisp and not drop the entire error stack here. When I say **node**, I actually mean node as in 'nodes in MongoDB replica-set' and not the service pods on Kubernetes.

Comment: Could you check the status of non-working pod - is it `running` state or something different? Could you confirm, that you can exec into broken pod and run some basic commands, check ping etc?

Comment: @Mikolaj Yes, I can exec into the broken pod and run netstat commands. And that pod is in a `running` state.